# Как изменить значение внутри тега, используя метод класса на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить значение внутри тега на конкретной карточки товара.
Имеется класс, на основе которого создаются отдельные объекты - экземпляры класса. Эти объекты и есть отдельные карточки товара на странице.

```
class ProductItem {
    constructor(name, description, category, image, price, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = 1;
    }

    increaseQuantity() {;
        this.quantity = this.quantity + 1;
        console.log("increase: ", this.name);
    }

    decreaseQuantity() {
        if (this.quantity > 1) {
            this.quantity = this.quantity - 1;
        }
    }

    events() {
        ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE.addEventListener("click", e => {
            if (e.target.getAttribute("data-atr") === "inBasket") {
                // вызвать ререндер корзины
            }
            if (e.target.getAttribute("data-atr") === "increase") {
                this.increaseQuantity();
                // увеличение на 1
            }
            if (e.target.getAttribute("data-atr") === "decrease") {
                // уменьшение на 1
            }
        });
    }

    getTemplate() {
        const html = `
      <div class="item-wrapper" data-name="${this.name}">
          <div class="item-wrapper__img"><img src="data${this.image}" alt="${this.category}"></div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__name">${this.name}</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__description" data-atr="${this.type}">${this.description}</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__price">Цена: ${this.price} руб.</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__count">
              <span>Количество</span>
            <div class="item-count__button">
              <button class="btn-count" data-atr="decrease">
                <i class='fas fa-minus' data-atr='decrease'></i>
              </button>
              <span class="item-count__field">${this.quantity}</span>
              <button class="btn-count" data-atr="increase">
                <i class='fas fa-plus' data-atr='increase'></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="item-wrapper__inbasket">
              <button class="btn-style basket-btn-add" data-name="${this.name}" data-atr="inBasket">
                В корзину
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>`;
        return html;
    }
}
```

Вызов рендера карточек происходит в другом классе, Арр. Так же в нём вешается обработчик событий.

```
class App {
    constructor() {}

    async getProductsItem(productType) {
        ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE.innerHTML = "";

        const products = await request.fetchData(productType); // массив с продуктами

        const productsItem = products.map(product => {
            const { name, description, category, image, price, type } = product;
            const item = new ProductItem(
                name,
                description,
                category,
                image,
                price,
                type
            );
            return item;
        });

        let content = "";
        productsItem.forEach(element => {
            content += element.getTemplate();
            element.events(); // вешаем eventListener
        });

        ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", content);
    }
}
```

Не знаю как изменить значение в поле, которое находится внутри шаблона.

```
<span class="item-count__field">${this.quantity}</span>
```

То есть в карточке товара есть кнопка (+) на которой весит дата-атрибут increase, соответственно при клике по ней у меня вызывается метод this.increaseQuantity() который и должен изменить значение в поле. Конечно можно обратиться к нему через querySelector, но может есть какие-то другие варианты лучше\правильнее?
Так же еще не могу понять(если посмотреть в метод this.increaseQuantity() у меня там есть console.log), почему по клику на кнопку(+) в консоле у меня отображается количество console.log()'ов равное количеству карточек на странице. Я ожидал, что мне покажет в консоле значение только того объекта у которого я нажимал по кнопе (+) :) Я как-то не правильно повесил обработчик событий....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE - это корневой враппер. Он есть в верстке изначально.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Ниже пример с комментариями.

3 класса - инпут, кнопка и App - корневой, рендерит 2 кнопки и инпут, содержит всю логику.

Все это жутко неудобно. Почитайте [документацию react](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), в разы быстрей придет понимание компонентного подхода, как для react в частности, так и для js в целом.

```js
// класс Input, render возвращает input
class Input {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
    this.notify = this.notify.bind(this); //биндим функцию оповещения
  }
  
  //ф-я оповещения, достаточно примитивно, просто принимает новое значение и устанавливает в элемент.
  notify(newValue) {
    this.element.value = newValue 
  }

  render() {
    //строим элементы, назначаем пропы и т.п.
    this.element = document.createElement('input')
    this.element.value = this.props.value || 0;
    this.element.disabled = true;
    this.props.subscribe(this.notify)
    //возвращаем элемент.
    return this.element;
  }
}

// класс Button, render возвращает button
class Button {
  constructor(props) {
    this.onClick = props.onClick; //в пропах принимаем ф-ю для click эвента
    this.value = props.value;
  }

  render() {
    this.element = document.createElement('input');
    this.element.type = "button";
    this.element.value = this.value;
    this.element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick) // назначаем на клик, эвент из пропов.
    return this.element; // возвращаем элемент.
  }
}

//родитель
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this); //биндим функции.
    this.decrease = this.decrease.bind(this); //биндим функции.
    this.subscribe = this.subscribe.bind(this) //биндим функции.
    
    
  }
  //ф-я подпики, передается в инпут, принимает коллбек ф-ю.
  subscribe(newSub) {
    this.subscriber = newSub;
  }
  //ф-я оповещения подписчика
  notify() {
    this.subscriber(this.count);
  }
  //ф-я увеличения
  increase() {
    this.count += 1;
    this.subscriber && this.notify(this.count)
  }
  //ф-я уменьшения
  decrease() {
    this.count = this.count - 1;
    this.subscriber && this.notify(this.count)//
  }

  render() {
  // Описываем чилдренов.
  this.children = [
      new Button({
        value: 'minus', //отправляем кнопке имя
        onClick: this.decrease // забинженая ф-я уменьшения count 
      }),
      new Input({
        value: this.count, //отправляем инпуту стартовое значение
        subscribe: this.subscribe //отправляем инпуту ф-ю для подписки на изменение count
      }),
      new Button({
        value: 'plus', //отправляем кнопке имя
        onClick: this.increase //забинженая ф-я увелиячения count
      })
    ]
    
    //перебираем массив чилдренов, инициируим у них render(), применяем их к родителю
    this.element = this.children.reduce((acc, child) => {
      acc.appendChild(child.render())
      return acc
    }, document.createElement('div'))
    return this.element // возвращаем элемент
  }
}

document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(new App().render()) //создаем элемент App и делаем его чилдреном #root
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий! Очень полезный, добавлю его себе в закладки) Такой вопрос, у Вас в примере по клику на кнопки меняется значение в инпуте(на 1). Инпут же является отдельным компонентом и в него прокидывается функция-подписки на изменение. У меня же есть поле ```<span class="item-count__field">${this.quantity}</span>``` и оно внутри самого класса, где я хочу изменить значение. Чтобы достучаться до него мне придётся использовать querySelector?

Comment: @kostya То, что я написал - это лишь корявый пример. 1. Использовать innerHtml неправильный путь, он ведет к проблемам, создавайте элементы только через createElement. 2. Чтобы понять, как изменить поле, нужно понять, что делает функция ProductItem.getTemplate() - при вызове она возвращает обычный текст, который вы вставляете в innerHtml родителя, т.е. для того, чтобы изменить значение элемента span class="item-count__field" вам либо надо заново создать весь innerHtml вызвав ф-ю и вставив текст в innerHtml родителя, либо обратиться к элементу span через DOM.